# configure TTL in elastic search with index template

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have  requirement to only store data for 10 days in elastic search which is coming through logstash. As I don't have too much data so I am taking approach for setting up TTL through index template.

Could anybody let me know what is exactly I  have to do.

I can go for creation of index template and in template file I have kept the following code in *default*.json file

```
{
   "_ttl" : {
    "enabled" : true,
    "default" : "10d"
 }  
}
```

But I am not sure where to keep this file and how that file is getting called. 
will it get called automatically or will I have to call manually.

Could anybody Please let me know the step by step configuration.

Answer (score 3):

The `_ttl` field has been [deprecated in ES 2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/mapping-ttl-field.html) and completely removed in ES 5.

What you should do instead is to use one index per timeframe (day, week, month) that makes sense for your use case.

In Logstash, simply use the following pattern for naming your index `"logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"` in your `elasticsearch` output.

Once you have that set up you can use the curator tool to [delete indices older than 10 days](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/ex_delete_indices.html), it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yes I know we can use curator.. But As I dont have too much data & my app user is not more than 2000 so want to go with the TTL approach..It would helpful if you can provide me the details to setup the TTL in elastic search.. Just little bit confuse where to put and exactly what to put

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: elastic search 2.3

Comment: If you really want to you can use the `_ttl` field in your template file, however, you need to know that this won't work anymore when you upgrade to ES 5. Please update your question with how your template file is looking.