# How to set TTL for documents in Elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am looking for a way to set TTL for document in my Elasticsearch index idealy by a property in my spring boot application

I tried to do it with curl and i got this error

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:9200/order_index/_mapping/order_doc' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "_ttl": {
        "enabled": true,
        "default": "24h"
    }
}'
```

error :

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_ttl : {default=24h, enabled=true}]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_ttl : {default=24h, enabled=true}]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Comment: _ttl was available back in Elasticsearch it seems, when I search the documentation. I am not aware of this feature in then current versions.

Comment: thank @P.J.Meisch in deed https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40945912/4604579

Comment: yes in deed not possible since version 5 https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ttl-documents/162712/7

Answer (score 3):

In the current latest version of Elasticsearch (7.15) the [_ttl is not yet supported](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html), you have to create the [Index Lifecycle Management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) policies.

So you have to declare policies to manage the datalifecyle and set this policies on your mapping.

Like this for example :
ILM :

```
PUT _ilm/policy/my_policy {   "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_primary_shard_size": "25GB" 
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "30d",
        "actions": {
          "delete": {} 
        }
      }
    }   } }
```

Mapping :

```
PUT test-index
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "index.lifecycle.name": "my_policy" 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First,** you create a policy to describe when an index will be deleted

PUT http://localhost:9200/_ilm/policy/delete_log_after_2day <- Your policy name

```
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "min_age": "0ms",
        "actions": {
          "set_priority": {
            "priority": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "2d", <-- Set your TTL here
        "actions": {
          "delete": {
            "delete_searchable_snapshot": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Next,** create a template to select which type of index will use this policy.

PUT http://localhost:9200/_index_template/delete_after2day_template

```
{
"index_patterns": [
    "test*" <-- Choose your index here
],
"template": {
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 1,
        "index.lifecycle.name": "delete_log_after_2day"
    }
}
}
```

Now, when you create a new index example: test001 it will be automatically deleted after 2 days.

**Note:**  for the old index, it will not assign to your new policy, so it won't be deleted except you assign it.

You can use this API to assign all old indexes to your policy

PUT http://localhost:9200/test*/_settings <--Your old index here, can use pattern

```
{
  "index": {
    "lifecycle": {
      "name": "delete_log_after_2day" <-- Your policy name
    }
  }
}
```

And then after your expiration date, all old indexes will be deleted completely.